# What type do lambdas get compiled into?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

As I know all data types must be known at compile time, and lambda is not a type. Does lambda got translated into `anonymous struct with operator()` or `std::function` wrapped?

For example,

```
std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [](int n&){n++;});
```

Comment: `std::function` has no language connections like `std::initializer_list` does.

Comment: It stems from my lack of knowledge. Purely random.

Comment: Lambda type is [unspecified](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7951377/what-is-the-type-of-lambda-when-deduced-with-auto-in-c11).

Comment: I just want to point out that the type of a lambda, albeit unspecified and non-expressible, *can* be deduced by templates. And *that*, I think, is powerful.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A variation of the [as-if rule](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if), the C++11 standard says:

> §5.1.2/3 *[..]* An implementation may define the closure type
>   differently from what is described below provided this does not alter
>   the observable behavior of the program other than by changing:
>
> — the size and/or alignment of the closure type,
>
> — whether the closure type is trivially copyable (Clause 9),
>
> — whether the closure type is a standard-layout class (Clause 9), or
>
> — whether the closure type is a POD class (Clause 9).

I believe this is what people mean when they say that it's [unspecified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7951377/what-is-the-type-of-lambda-when-deduced-with-auto-in-c11). However what's guaranteed as already stated in the other answers is the following:

Original author: [Lightness Races in Orbit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20825525/3920237)

> > `[C++11: 5.1.2/3]:` **The type of the *lambda-expression*** (which is also the type of the closure object) **is a unique, unnamed
> >     non-union class type** — called the *closure type* — whose properties
> >     are described below. This class type is not an aggregate (8.5.1). The
> >     closure type is declared in the smallest block scope, class scope, or
> >     namespace scope that contains the corresponding *lambda-expression*.
> >     *[..]*
>
> The clause goes on to list varying properties of this type. Here are
>   some highlights:
>
> > `[C++11: 5.1.2/5]:` The closure type for a *lambda-expression* has a public `inline` function call operator (13.5.4) whose parameters and
> >     return type are described by the *lambda-expression*’s
> >     *parameter-declaration-clause* and *trailing-return-type* respectively. *[..]*
> >
> > `[C++11: 5.1.2/6]:` The closure type for a *lambda-expression* with no *lambda-capture* has a public non-virtual non-explicit const
> >     conversion function to pointer to function having the same parameter
> >     and return types as the closure type’s function call operator. The
> >     value returned by this conversion function shall be the address of a
> >     function that, when invoked, has the same effect as invoking the
> >     closure type’s function call operator.

Answer (score 13):

From the standard §5.1.2.3:

> The type of the *lambda-expression*... is a unique, unnamed non-union class type

It is its own type. Every time. So for instance:

```
auto a = []{ return 1; };
auto b = []{ return 1; };
```

`a` and `b` will necessarily have different types. They are both convertible to `std::function<int()>`, but not to each other:

```
std::function<int()> c = a; // OK
a = b; // NOPE
```

Adding a few more examples to add some clarity:

```
decltype(a) a2 = a; // OK, explicitly specifying the correct type

template <typename F>
void foo(F f) { ... }

foo(a); // calls foo<decltype(a)>, not foo<std::function<int()>
```

Comment: This does not answer my question. I know lambda does not have a type (as I stated in the question). My question is how they are compiled since they don't have type.

Comment: @texasbruce You misunderstand. They *do* have a type. It's just *unique* and *unnamed*. In my example, you can do `using T = decltype(a); T a2 = a;` That will compile just fine.

Comment: @texasbruce: The answer says that the type of a lambda expression is a unique, unnamed non-union class type. That's a different statement from "does not have a type". A lambda *does* have a type, but the type does not have a name.

Comment: @Barry, I believe `using T = decltype(a)` is actually illegal. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4846540/c11-lambda-in-decltype

Comment: @sfjac He's using `decltype` on an expression instead of the resulting object. Once we have `a`, it's just an object like any other. Example: http://ideone.com/V7lXdg

Answer (score 6):

A lambda expression constructs an unnamed type, with each one having a different type. They are not `std::function` implementations. More info is provided here:
[What is a lambda expression in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627098/what-is-a-lambda-expression-in-c11/7627218#7627218) and here: [How to convert a lambda to an std::function using templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13358672/how-to-convert-a-lambda-to-an-stdfunction-using-templates)

You can unveil the type on your specific compiler with a trick like this:

```
void foo(int);

int main() {
    auto a = []{ return 1; };
    auto b = []{ return 1; };

    foo(a);

    foo(b);

    return 0;
}
```

Compiling with clang on my mac gives:

```
/Users/jcrotinger/ClionProjects/so_lambda_type/main.cpp:11:5: error: no matching function for call to 'foo'
    foo(a);
    ^~~
/Users/jcrotinger/ClionProjects/so_lambda_type/main.cpp:5:6: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 
'<lambda at /Users/jcrotinger/ClionProjects/so_lambda_type/main.cpp:8:14>' to 'int' for 1st argument
void foo(int);
     ^
/Users/jcrotinger/ClionProjects/so_lambda_type/main.cpp:13:5: error: no matching function for call to 'foo'
    foo(b);
    ^~~
/Users/jcrotinger/ClionProjects/so_lambda_type/main.cpp:5:6: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 
'<lambda at /Users/jcrotinger/ClionProjects/so_lambda_type/main.cpp:9:14>' to 'int' for 1st argument
void foo(int);
```

@Barry points out that you can use `typeid` instead. If I print out `typeid(a).name()` and `typeid(b).name()` on my system, I get:

```
Z4mainE3$_0
Z4mainE3$_1
```

which demangle to

```
main::$_0
main::$_1
```

Just wanted to include this for completeness. I actually find the error message version a little more informative. :)

Comment: So it is anonymous struct?

Comment: As per @texasbruce's elaborations, they have a type, but it is an implementation detail.

Comment: @sfjac If you really want to look at the type, you can just use `typeid()` and pass it through a [demangler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/281818/unmangling-the-result-of-stdtype-infoname)

Comment: @Barry A demangler is unlikely to be necessary, when one is already provided with the gcc toolchain. [c++filt](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/c_002b_002bfilt.html)

Comment: @remyabel sure, but maybe you want to write a function that prints types during code runtime? `c++filt` is great for checking out symbol files though.